# Custom FAI Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: system-installation, automation, custom-installer

I know the **FAI** tool that allows to create a **fully automatic** and customizable Debian installation image, and I love it.

But at the moment **it doesn't offer the tool for Ubuntu**, which is sad.

I would love to **create an image of Ubuntu 20 that would install automatically** with all the settings I want, like FAI, but I don't know how to do it.

Would you know of a **simple solution with a GUI** to create this kind of image? All the forums I've found that talk about it are from a very long time ago.

If not, is there a **clear enough documentation** for this kind of project? I suck at searching on the internet ^^

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: https://fai-project.org/  "Installs Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS, RHEL, SUSE, ..." ?

Comment: @Rinzwind It only allows you to modify Debian, not Ubuntu as I would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally done what i've wanted, by using preseed and it works great <3